# Combining multiple Queries to single one postgres based on revision

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a newbie into postgresql and database. I am trying to prepare a birt report where I have to take data from 5 table based on parameters Unit, Year and Month. Results are saved as revision in each table and I have to pick latest revision data

The individual query as below

```
select wccb_pc$p,wccb_abufm,wccb_budm,wccb_revno 
from wb_capacity_chrg_bill_month 
where unit=? and bill_year=? and bill_month=? order by wccb_revno desc limit 1;

select wocb_wvf$p, wocb_flag, wocb_revno 
from wb_output_chrg_bill_month 
where unit=? and bill_year=? and bill_month=? order by wocb_revno desc limit 1;

select su_sum, revno 
from wb_startup_pay_month 
where unit=? and bill_year=? and bill_month=? order by revno desc limit 1;

select sdm, revno  
from wb_startup_ded_month 
where unit=? and bill_year=? and bill_month=? order by revno desc limit 1;

select dasm, dagcm, dasagcm, revno 
from billing_as_agc_month 
where unit=? and bill_year=? and bill_month=? order by revno desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Are the 5 tables related?  Can you use a `JOIN` to put them all together?

Comment: Sounds as if you are looking for a UNION, but for that you would need to have the same number (and types) of columns in each query

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a `JOIN`?

```
select a.wccb_revno, a.wccb_pc$p, a.wccb_abufm, a.wccb_budm,
       b.wocb_wvf$p, b.wocb_flag,
       c.su_sum,
       d.sdm,
       e.dasm, e.dagcm, e.dasagcm
  from wb_capacity_chrg_bill_month a
  JOIN wb_output_chrg_bill_month b ON (a.wccb_revno = b.wocb_revno)
  JOIN wb_startup_pay_month c ON (b.wocb_revno = c.revno)
  JOIN wb_startup_ded_month d ON (c.revno = d.revno)
  JOIN billing_as_agc_month e ON (d.revno = e.revno)
where a.unit=? and a.bill_year=? a.and bill_month=? order by wccb_revno desc limit 1;
```

Depending on whether all 5 tables are guaranteed to have a `revno` in common, you may need to change your `JOIN` to a `FULL OUTER JOIN`